# after installing ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated my android built not working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-proguard

Error: Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.

i want ionic cordova plugin cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated for notification but build is crash after installed this plugin if i remove this plugin then my app is working

i try to use fcm plugin with android 8.0.0 with cordova-plugin-googleplus 7.0.0 and  i try with android 7.4.1 and 6.4.0 with cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this!..

step 1 `ionic cordova platform rm android`

step 2 go to `/plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/src/android/FCMPlugin.gradle`

change like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.+'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

step 3 `ionic cordova platform add android`

step 4 Goto `/platforms/android/project.properties`

Change like the numbers into 11.4.2

```
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
```

demo project.properties file

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-badge/mobile-badge.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/mobile-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-local-notification/mobile-localnotification.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/mobile-ignorelinterrors.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker/mobile-androidtarget.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.6=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/mobile-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-v4:27.+
cordova.gradle.include.7=twitter-connect-plugin/mobile-twitter.gradle
cordova.system.library.12=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0
```

step 5 ionic cordova build android

```
Note :: Don't forgot to add google-services.json file in root directory, main_project/google-services.json
```

Comment: sir above solution is fixed but got another  error generated: 
  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue and yesterday we solve this problem with this answer:

**Answer:1**

This is due to the firebase updates on April 05. Here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_april_02_2019, I found the last working versions and adjusted my project.properties accordingly like so

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0 
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1 
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

Here all dependencies are locked to the specific version (Update - April 02, 2019) instead of +, which would get you the latest version thus breaking the build process.

Now I can build successfully! I hope it helps!

Ref: [page](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1057#issuecomment-490000068)

**Answer: 2**

A wonderful person opened a pull request 31 in the cordova-firebase-plugin official repo and it works.

Steps I did:

```
1 - Remove cordova-firebase-plugin with ionic cordova plugin remove cordova- 
firebase-plugin

2 - Install: ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue

3 - rm -rf node_modules/ plugins/ platforms/android package-lock.json

4 - ionic cordova platform add android && npm install

5 - In my case, I also use a firebase js library in an old version because the newest ones are not working for me. With that library I always need to reinstall it manually after all the previous steps, so also I did: npm install firebase@4.12.1.
```

And now it’s working.

ref: [Page](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/50?u=gokujy)

Comment: thanks for help , tried your solution still same error 

Found com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+, but version 10.+ is needed for the google-services plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Korean who develops with Cordova

I solved as below.
cordova-plugin-admob-free and
Library conflict with cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated.

I changed only the ads version and ran it as shown below.

I am not sure if the content will be delivered using Google Translate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyYbU.png)

/platforms/android/project.properties

cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/helloworld-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0